# How to creating social share buttons in php?

Tags: php, html

The thumbnail and title not working properly when I share the blogs to social media like Facebook, LinkedIn, and Twitter.

I have made a blogging website where I want to share the blog/blogs to different social media like Facebook, LinkedIn, and Twitter. I have made the website in PHP.
The meta tags which I have used are the following-

```
$bid = $_GET['blog_id'];

$blog_page_title = $row['blog_page_title'];
$share_image = "../images/$blog_image";
$share_url = "http://localhost/tui-new-website2/mains/blog?blog_id=$bid";
$blog_content  = $row['blog_content'];

<meta property="og:title" <?php echo 'content="'.$blog_title.'"'; ?>/>
<meta property="og:image" <?php echo 'content="'.$share_image.'"'; ?>/>
<meta property="og:url" <?php echo 'content="'.$share_url.'"'; ?>/>
<meta property="og:description" <?php echo 'content="'.$blog_content.'"'; ?>/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="http://localhost/tui-new-website2/index"/>
```

Inside the HTML code I have used the following codes-

```
<div class="social-links-details">
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php echo $share_url;?>" target="_blank"><img src="../images/fa.png" alt="Facebook logo"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
 <a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=<?php echo $blog_title;?>&url=<?php echo $share_url;?>" target="_blank"><img src="../images/tw.png" alt="Twitter logo"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
 <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="../images/yt.png" alt="Youtube logo"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
 <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php echo $share_url;?>" target="_blank"><img src="../images/ln.png" alt="Linkedln logo"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
 <a href="https://www.instagram.com/theunitedindian/" target="_blank"><img src="../images/ig.png" alt="Instagram logo"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
</div>
```

The output I am getting is as following-

[image]

Comment: `not working is a poor description`! Add a sufficient explanation with details to it. What is not working? How is it not working? What output was expected, and what output do you get? What error messages are received?

Comment: `$share_url = "http://localhost/...";` - you can not "share" localhost URLs. The networks need to be able to request those URLs, for them to _see_ your meta data in the first place. Plus, what good would sharing a URL other _users_ can't access either, do?